# LINQ to Entities: Get more recent date from each group

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to group **Reports** by **Type** and return the most recent **Created** date for each Report Type, using *LINQ to Entities*. I did my research and read lots of questions and most of them are solved using a similar query than mine:

```
var query = ctx.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Reports
         .GroupBy(i => i.ReportType)
         .Select(i => new { name = i.Key, y = i.Max(h => h.DateCreated) });
```

But I get this error:

**`A query cannot return non-Entity types that contain embedded entities`**

What am I doing wrong? Is it because it's LINQ-to-Entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is quite descriptive. Your anonymous type contains a property which is typed as an entity (`name = i.Key` part). You can't do that, because LINQ to Entities would not be able to track changes to these entities.

You can take just some of the properties from `ReportType` instead of entire entity:

```
var query = ctx.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Reports
     .GroupBy(i => i.ReportType)
     .Select(i => new { name = i.Key.Name, y = i.Max(h => h.DateCreated) });
```

`i.Key.Name` is just an example. Your entity probably has different property/properties you care about.